# Recurring database entries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, recurring-events

Quick question about recurring DB entries.

Say I have users posting their Trips on a platform. Now, the user can say these Trips are recurring - she/he makes that trip every Tuesday and Thursday.

To make things even more interesting, say that every Trip has Requests attached to it, that other users can make. And they can make these Requests for every recurring trip.

Any ideas on how would I handle a case like this one on the back-end? Using Rails and Postgres.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would build a new Model called recurring or whatever you want to call it, belongs_to the Trip, if a Trip is recurring you use this new Model to establish the recurrence.  As for the requests - you can create a has_many through relationship probably to make it work.  What we really need to see is what you have already for Trips and Requests and what you've tried for recurrence.  (I'm a big fan of normalization though, you could do the recurrence within the simple trip table but in your example you need two 'recurrences' unless you know a way to have one attribute that can select two days)

Answer (score 1):

```
User
  has_many :trips

Trip
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :requests

Request
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :trip
```

Add `recurring_start` and `recurring_end` attributes on `Trip`, and perhaps a `recur` attribute on `Request`. I don't know that you need to create any additional records for each Trip then, do you?

If so, you want your business logic handling that. Something like Sidekiq with a Query object that fetches Trips that are due for recurrence and creates the new trip with (for example) updated start and end dates…

```
class Trip < ApplicationModel
  scope :recurring, -> { where(recur: true) }
  scope :due_for_recurrence, -> { recurring.where(Trip.arel_table[:end_date].lt(Time.now)) }
end
```

You can use something like [DeepCloneable](https://github.com/moiristo/deep_cloneable) if you want to automatically clone/dup associated records as well.

Comment: Does this work if the recurrences are, like in his example, on every tuesday and thursday?  For me the instinct is a related Model to allow for the most flexibility on recurrences but maybe I'm over normalizing?

Comment: @MageeWorld Depends on how that logic is already implemented, and how these records are utilized in the application. Assuming you a `request` is something like a notification, a query could easily pull all valid gis-bound trips that fit the temporal conditions, then push notifications to the desired channels without needing to create individual records.

Comment: @coreyward this looks legit, thank you for the tips. Upvoting your answer until I get some time to test this. Which is soon. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Since every trip can have different requests, they all need their own individual ID. It would make sense to treat them exactly the same as non-recurring trips, except for one situation: when the creator of the trips wants to edit or delete all the instances of a recurring trip. For that, you may want to make an additional table for recurring trips, with a one-to-many relation from recurring trip IDs to trip IDs, and allow users to own recurring trip IDs as well as trip IDs. That way the user interface can display the two kinds logically and they won't get lost.

Just make sure that whenever a trip is edited or deleted, the recurring trip table is updated. That could either be accomplished by simply disallowing edits or deletion to trips that are part of a recurring trip, or make the trips table store an optional recurring trip ID.